# Ubuntu 23.04 audio lag when enabled lock screen

Tags: sound, pipewire

Ubuntu 23.04
All updates done
`sudo lshw -C sound`

```
  *-multimedia
       descrizione: Audio device
       prodotto: 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
       fornitore: Intel Corporation
       id fisico: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       nome logico: card0
       nome logico: /dev/snd/controlC0
       nome logico: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
       nome logico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
       nome logico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
       nome logico: /dev/snd/pcmC0D2c
       versione: 00
       larghezza: 64 bits
       orologio: 33MHz
       capacità: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configurazione: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       risorse: irq:38 memoria:f7310000-f7313fff
```

Everytime my screen goes black, the audio from Youtube,Spotify o other player, starts to lag